# Need to create an oob quick poll webpart with a pie chart graphical representation of responses in sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, chart-web-part

i need to create a quick poll webpart on my intranet home page which will also show a graphical representation of all the user responses in the form of a pie chart(with percentages as tool tip)

i created a survey intially for this. but a survey can be answered only once by a user. i mean if there are more than one questions in the survey user cant answer them as he already answered one question.

the other part is i was suggested to use google api to chart my response data which wil b stored in a list.

but for this in 2010 we used to have a chartwebpart-> which is discontinued in 2013.
and the option now is excel services.

i hardly worked on excel services.i need to achieve this using foundation 2013 only

any help on this is appreciated.

regards,
Keerthi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually recommend not using a pie chart - they are one of the hardest things for human eyes to evaluate.  A simple bar chart, vertical or horizontal, would be much easier to interpret - and you could also do it with XSL if you wanted to.

If you decide you want something prettier then [Amcharts](http://www.amcharts.com/) is another alternative to Google charts.

I have done this before with jQuery and a couple of lists.  One list allows the comms team to create new polls with a question and handful of answer options.  You can also add things like a start and end date so they can prepopulate.  The second list then stores the responses.  jQuery tests to see if the user has already responded and if they have then it displays the results - otherwise it displays the question and answer options.

Comment: Hi dave.. thanks for the reply.. but the requirement is to show up a 3d sliced pie chart for the responses to the question. i also need to implement this in sharepoint foundation 2013.. so please suggest me ways to achieve this..

Comment: and dave as i am trying this for the first time n also am not left with time for research..so please can i depend on u for the step wise implementation of the jquery n lists u were talking about... help is much anticipated n appreciated...

Comment: can someone help me on this regard.......!!!!